# Unwanted header/footer in iPhone Keyboard xamarin.ios

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I'm working on the Xamarin.Forms application, where I've some Entry field. When the keyboard pops up there are some grey header and footer is appearing in the keyboard. Could anyone help me on that. Please find the attached screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Strange, what version of Forms are you using? Are you doing anything with the keyboard? Any custom renderers?

Comment: Hi,
Xamarin.Forms version - 2.3.4.224

No Custom renderers, only default keyboard